# Infragistics IgniteUI Grid set Datasource(Create Data Access Class or use Entity Framework)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, infragistics, ignite-ui

i recently started to use infragistics, i have got the infragistics version 2013.2...
I am creating a project using mvc 4.0 , and i am trying to use igniteui components...in this case igGrid..
Is it possible to assign datasource to entity framework ? i saw the youtube video displaying this case, but i am getting errors.
What is the best way to go, use entity framework model or create my own class?

GridController

```
namespace MvcApplication5.Controllers
{
public class GridController : Controller
{
    public MvcApplication5Context db = new MvcApplication5Context();
    [GridDataSourceAction]
    public ActionResult GetProducts()
    {


       return View(MvcApplication5.Models.ProductModel.GetProductList());
    }
    private DataTable GetCustomerDataTable()
    {

        SqlConnection conn = (SqlConnection)db.Database.Connection;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = conn)
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Product", con))
            {
                adapter.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }


 }
}
```

My Products Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;

namespace MvcApplication5.Models
{
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SupplierID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string QuantityPerUnit { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> UnitsInStock { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> UnitsOnOrder { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> ReorderLevel { get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public bool Discontinued { get; set; }
    public string CategoryImageUrl { get; set; }
}

public class ProductModel
{
    public static IQueryable<Product> GetProductList()
    {
        MvcApplication5Context db = new MvcApplication5Context();
        var Products = from c in db.Products
                       orderby c.ID
                       select c;
        return Products.AsQueryable<Product>();
    }
}
}
```

And my view;

```
@using Infragistics.Web.Mvc
@model IQueryable<MvcApplication5.Models.ProductModel>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "GetProducts";
 }

<h2>GetProducts</h2>
 @(Html.Infragistics().Grid<MvcApplication5.Models.ProductModel>()
    .ID("grid1")
    .Height("400px")
    .Width("100%")
    .AutoGenerateColumns(true)
    .DefaultColumnWidth("150px")

    .DataSource(Url.Action("GetProducts"))
    .DataBind()
    .Render()
)
```

I have made some test, and i have manage to create a datatable and bind it to the iqGrid..
The video is low resolution and i cant see the last part...

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

It works now, the difference was instead of using a local db connection, i created a new connction to a sql server database..